# Neumann heat semigroup and first eigenvalue of $\Delta$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, semigroups

> Let $\left(e^{t \Delta}\right)_{t \geqslant 0}$ be the Neumann heat semigroup in $\Omega$, and let $\lambda_{1}>0$ denote the first nonzero eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ under Neumann boundary conditions. Then there exist constants $C_{1}, \ldots, C_{4}$ depending on $\Omega$ only which have the following properties.
> (i) If $1 \leqslant q \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$ then ...

I don't know the definition of Neumann heat semigroup and first nonzero eigenvalue of $\Delta$?

If you know anything about them I thank you to tell me.

This is lemma 1.3., from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039610000562).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: It would help if you could include the source of this passage that you are (presumably) quoting.

Comment: [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039610000562) lemma 1.3.

Comment: Did you try reading [22]? Likely they define it there.

Comment: I can't find them there? with pages define them?